# Calculo de horas com desconto de fins de semana

Tags: php

Estou implementando em uma aplicação a verificação do tempo em que um dado foi criado no banco de dados. Essa informação de data e criada pela função nativa do `php` `time()` que gera um valor que e gravado no banco como uma `string`. Nesta verificação tem um alerta quando passar de 72 horas sem tratativa destas informações, onde pego o valor da `string` da criação e somo mais as horas do alerta e verifico se o valor e maior que o `time()` atual. Se maior, passou do tempo de tratativa. Até ai tudo funciona normalmente. O que acontece e que preciso descontar da verificação o tempo dos fins de semana, exatamente as 00:00 de sábado até as 11:59:59.

Alguém teria uma ideia de como posso fazer isso diretamente pelo código? No momento a unica solução que imaginei em criar um tempo de pausa no banco de dados com os valores de inicial e final.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o [strtotime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) para subtrair horas a uma data pre-establecida:

```
$data_final = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($data_sem_descanso));
```

Edit, o código abaixo retorna o numero de dias de um mes subtraindo os dias de descanso:

```
function numDiasDescansoMes($mes, $ano, $diaDescanso1, $diaDescanso2=-1){

    $num_dias_mes = date("t", strtotime("01-$mes-$ano"));

    $n_dias_descanso = 0;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_dias_mes; $i++){

        $data_loop = $i."-$mes-$ano";
        $dia_semana = date("w", strtotime($data_loop));
        if( ($dia_semana == $diaDescanso1) || ($dia_semana == $diaDescanso2) )
            $n_dias_descanso++;
    }

    return $num_dias_mes-$n_dias_descanso;

}
```

Não é bem o que pretende mas neste momento estou vou-me ausentar. Penso que pelo codigo acima poderá facilmente desenvolver uma função para fazer o que pretende.

Comment: Mais preciso que seja automático. Que sempre retire sábados e domingos de uma linha do tempo onde possa ter varias semanas

Comment: Fiz algo parecido para um projecto, vou ver se encontro.

Comment: Veja se o codigo novo que coloquei ajuda.

Comment: Então, tudo chega em timestamp unix. as vezes preciso tirar de n semanas. Não dentro somente de um mês. Preciso pegar dessa linha de tempo e ir retirando sábados e domingos.